# Как программно открыть ссылку браузера? С++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

Не знаю, как можно это сделать. Пытался найти пример в интернете, но ничего. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: D какой операционной системе? Что понимать под "открыть ссылку браузера"? Вы хотите запустить браузер, чтобы открыть в нем определенную ссылку? Или открыть "ссылку браузера" какой-то своей программой? Понимаете, если нет точного ТЗ, ответ будет один — ХЗ!

Comment: нашел вместо тебя, держи https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347950/how-do-i-open-a-url-from-c

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Но почему-то не работает, не происходит ничего при открытии консоли. Система Win10. visual studio 2022. Хочу, чтобы при запуске программы открывалась вкладка в браузере по умолчанию. То есть, ссылка открывалась в браузере по умолчанию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вот так.

```
ShellExecute(0,"open",url,NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```

Вот вполне работоспособный пример, компилируемый VC++ 2019 и работающий под Windows 10:

```
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment(lib,"shell32")

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ShellExecute(0,"open","http://www.google.com",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
}
```

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Какую библиотеку подключать если использовать первый вариант?

Comment: только windows.h?

Comment: Еще раз и медленно — это весь текст. Записываем его в файл `prog.cpp`. Компиляция — `cl prog.cpp`. Запуск `prog.exe`. Что еще непонятно?